# Dynkin's formula for Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff on Wikipedia

Tags: sequences-and-series, lie-groups, lie-algebras, generating-functions

The [Wikipedia page for the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Dynkin%27s_formula) gives that
[image: BCH per Wikipedia]
imposing only the restriction that $r_j$ and $s_j$ be nonnegative integers. I wonder whether this should not be tightened to $r_j,s_j\ge1$ possibly excepting $r_1$ and $s_n$ (which comports with what my gut says should be the "standard form", as it is equally symmetric but a bit simpler). Otherwise, commutators could arise in many ways, which seem to not give the right coefficient. Consider for instance $[YXXY]$, which per the expansion following in the article has coefficient $-\frac{1}{24}$. Notice that $[YXXY]=[XYXY]=-[YXYX]=-[XYYX]$. These would then get coefficients: [EDIT: corrected following Eero Hakavuori's comment, and this gives the correct coefficient]

- $[YXXY]$

  - $(r,s)=(0110,1001)$ with coefficient $-\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{4}$
  - $(r,s)=(020,101)$ with coefficient $\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{2}$
  - $(r,s)=(02,11)$ with coefficient $-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{2}=-\frac{1}{16}$
  - $(r,s)=(011,101)$ with coefficient $\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{12}$
- $[XYXY]$

  - $(r,s)=(11,11)$ with coefficient $-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4}=-\frac{1}{8}$
  - $(r,s)=(101,011)$ with coefficient $\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{12}$
  - $(r,s)=(110,101)$ with coefficient $\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{12}$
  - $(r,s)=(1010,0101)$ with coefficient $-\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{4}=-\frac{1}{16}$
- $-[XYYX]$

  - $(r,s)=(11,20)$ with coefficient $-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{2}=-\frac{1}{16}$
  - $(r,s)=(1001,0110)$ with coefficient $-\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{4}=-\frac{1}{16}$
  - $(r,s)=(101,020)$ with coefficient $\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{24}$
  - $(r,s)=(101,110)$ with coefficient $\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{12}$
- $-[YXYX]$

  - $(r,s)=(011,110)$ with coefficient $\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{12}$
  - $(r,s)=(0101,1010)$ with coefficient $-\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{4}$

and this is as far as I can tell an exhaustive accounting of (nonvanishing) terms in the BCH exponent with 2 $X$s and 2 $Y$s. (Here, I write e.g. "$r=1010$" to mean $(r_1,r_2,r_3,r_3)=(1,0,1,0)$.) The total coefficient is $-\frac{1}{24}$. <s>which is off by a factor of 2, so that factor of 2 could be a mistake on my part or just a coincidence. Can someone explain the correct way to read this formula?</s>

Comment: The list of terms does not seem exhaustive. For instance $(r,s)=(0110,1001)$ is missing from the $[YXXY]$ case. Try creating the list for each $X,Y$-word by starting from the 'maximally separated' case of length 4 and enumerating all the shorter $(r,s)$ terms by collapsing neighboring terms, e.g. $(0110,1001)$ can be collapsed between the first and second terms to $((0+1)10,(1+0)01)=(110,101)$.

Comment: Yes, I see now, thank you – it does give the correct answer, and I've updated the body to reflect this.